# How do I fix the CSP errors I have?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm using NextJs@12 and I'm trying to set CSP for my application. I keep getting errors logged into my console and I have no idea what I'm doing wrongly. This is the policy I currently have in my netx.config file.

```
  {
    key: "Content-Security-Policy",
    value: "default-src 'self' cdn.jsdelivr.net; script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shoelace-style/shoelace@2.0.0-beta.47/dist/chunks/chunk.HAL7R4WT.js https://embed.tawk.to/_s/v4/app/61adcafd0e1/js/twk-chunk-vendors.js https://js.paystack.co/v1/inline.js https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self' https://eljsuiwhwbb5lp5lmre5eifzuu.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com https://embed.tawk.to https://va.tawk.to https://vitals.vercel-insights.com https://vsb75.tawk.to https://vsb89.tawk.to https://www.google-analytics.com wss://eljsuiwhwbb5lp5lmre5eifzuu.appsync-realtime-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com wss://vsb75.tawk.to wss://vsb89.tawk.to; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://embed.tawk.to https://fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' data: https://embed.tawk.to https://res.cloudinary.com https://tawk.link https://www.google-analytics.com;",
  },
```

And this is the error so far: [image]

I need help in solving this. I have been on it all day.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally just have the hosts as sources in CSP, not the full url. I'm assuming your on https, so you don't need to specify that, but should keep wss in your policy. Try this instead:

default-src 'self' cdn.jsdelivr.net; script-src 'self' cdn.jsdelivr.net embed.tawk.to js.paystack.co [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) [www.googletagmanager.com](http://www.googletagmanager.com) 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self' eljsuiwhwbb5lp5lmre5eifzuu.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com embed.tawk.to va.tawk.to vitals.vercel-insights.com vsb75.tawk.to vsb89.tawk.to [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) wss://eljsuiwhwbb5lp5lmre5eifzuu.appsync-realtime-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com wss://vsb75.tawk.to wss://vsb89.tawk.to; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdn.jsdelivr.net embed.tawk.to fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' data: embed.tawk.to res.cloudinary.com tawk.link www.google-analytics.com;"

Comment: this is what happens when I try `Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' cdn.jsdelivr.net". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Comment: Then you will have to add that hostname to default-src or font-src (which you will need to add). Either the blocked font was already there in the first place, but not shown in the screenshot, or it appeared after a script or style was allowed to load.

Comment: CSP integration in Next.js is not easy and that's why I created this NPM package to solve such kind of problems:
https://github.com/guydumais/next-strict-csp